# aarch64-elf-g++ -fPIC gives different values for local and global symbol

Tags: g++, arm64, fpic

Under windows 10, using cross-compiling toolchain provided by `linaro`, which has the full name `gcc-linaro-7.2.1-2017.11-i686-mingw32_aarch64-elf`(can be searched through internet), to compile the following code snippet:

```
// file test.cpp

// ASM_DEFINE_LOCAL_SYM and ASM_DEFINE_GLOBAL_SYM defines assembler symbol,
// one is local and the other is global, as their name indicated
#define ASM_DEFINE_LOCAL_SYM(sym) __asm__ __volatile__(#sym ":\n\t")
#define ASM_DEFINE_GLOBAL_SYM(sym) __asm__ __volatile__(".global " #sym " \n\t;" #sym ":\n\t")

void testIfLocalSymWrongs()
{
    kout << "func address = " <<reinterpret_cast<uint64_t>(testIfLocalSymWrongs) << "\n";
    extern char local[];
    extern char global[];

    ASM_DEFINE_LOCAL_SYM(local);
    ASM_DEFINE_GLOBAL_SYM(global);
    kout << "local = " << reinterpret_cast<uint64_t>(local) << "\n";
    kout << "global = " << reinterpret_cast<uint64_t>(global) << "\n";
}
```

The code is not complete, as I am testing a mini kernel in a baremetal environment.In above code, `kout` just writes characters to a serial port(when using hardware like `raspberry pi 3`) or the console(when using emulator such as `QEMU`), but it need not to be complete, I think.
Whatever, the compile command is `aarch64-elf-g++ -fPIC test.cpp .... -o test`, and use `aarch64-elf-objcopy` to generate `kernel.test.img`, which contains just binary code, other data like elf headers are stripped.

Run it on QEMU:`qemu-system-aarch64 -machine virt,gic-version=3 -cpu cortex-a53 -smp 1 -m 1G -nographic -serial stdio  -bios kernel.test.img`
gives the  following output:

```
func address = 3c64
local = 3c64
global = 3cc0
```

whereas you can see `func address` is the same with `local`, and `local` is different with `global`, which is exactly not what we expected.

The core problem is when you use `-fPIC` to compile, local symbol and global symbol have different value when they should be the same.

Maybe `aarch64-elf-g++` generated a wrong  `.got` section? But I am not sure, can anyone explain this?

Answer (score 0):

Solved this problem after one day, sorry to answer so late now.
It's a difference between compiling option `-fPIC` and `-pie`, when you use the latter one to replace the former one, the program will give correct(as expected) output.

So when compiling using cross toolchains like `aarch64-elf-g++`, to generate `position independent code`, you'd prefer `-pie` rather than `-fPIC`.

Please test it yourself and if possible reply to this answer.